# Vertical text working in Safari 6

Tags: html, css, safari

I am trying to show vertical text in a webpage.  I have it working in all browsers including Safari 5 for Windows except it doesn't work in Safari 6 on a Mac.  In Safari 6, no text in the inner div appears.  How do I get this to work in Safari 6 and still keep it working in other browsers?

Here is the HTML:

```
<table  class="dashboard-table-rotating">
  <tr>
    <th class="dashboard-header-cell">
      <div class="vertical-text">
        <div class="vertical-text-inner">Goals, Objectives, Priorities</div>
      </div>
    </th>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
.dashboard-table-rotating th {
  border: thin solid #000000;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}

.vertical-text {
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 3em;
  text-align: left;
}

.vertical-text-inner {
  display: inline-block;
  white-space: nowrap;
  line-height: 1.5;
  transform: translate(0px,100%) rotate(-90deg);
  -webkit-transform: translate(0px,100%) rotate(-90deg);
  transform-origin: 0 0;
}

@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) {
  /*Only used for Safari*/
 ::i-block-chrome,.vertical-text-inner {
    padding-top: 15px;   
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just needed to simplify things some.  This got it to work:

```
<table class="dashboard-table-rotating">
  <tr>
    <th>
      <div class="vertical-header">
        Goals, Objectives, Priorities
      </div>
    </th>
  </tr>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
.vertical-header {
  -moz-transform: rotate(-90.0deg); /* FF3.5+ */
  -ms-transform: rotate(-90.0deg); /* IE9+ */
  -o-transform: rotate(-90.0deg); /* Opera 10.5 */
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-90.0deg); /* Safari 3.1+, Chrome */
  transform: rotate(-90.0deg); /* Standard */
  width:32px;
  white-space:nowrap;
}

.dashboard-table-rotating th {
  border: thin solid #000000;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  padding-left: 8px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

check this **fiddle**

**http://jsfiddle.net/wzr4crfr/4/**

CSS

```
.dashboard-table-rotating th {
  border: thin solid #000000;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: bottom;
    width: 40px;
position: absolute;
}

.vertical-text {
  display: table;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: left;
}

.vertical-text-inner {
  display: table-cell;
  white-space: nowrap;
  line-height: 1.5;
  transform: translate(0px,100%) rotate(-90deg);
  -webkit-transform: translate(0px,100%) rotate(-90deg);
  transform-origin: 0 0;
}
```

i am not sure it is fixed your issue, because i dont have safari

Comment: That's closer, the vertical text now appears in Safari.  But the cell is too wide in Safari and IE, though it looks fine in Firefox.  I'd like it to be about 40px wide, but it sets the width of the cell to what the width of the text would be if it were horizontal.  I haven't found a way to make it the right width.  Can you or someone else fix that?

Comment: Sorry, but adding the "position: absolute" adversely affected how other cells were rendered.  I added more cells to the fiddle so it can be seen how they would be affected.  See this: http://jsfiddle.net/wzr4crfr/6/

Comment: Sorry, but it's truncating the cell contents.